# How to find node that a file is attached to

Tags: views, nodes, files

There is a file that I want to find the node it is attached to, or at least the user that submitted it.

I was able to create a view that finds the file itself but when I a field for node id, it displays nothing.

Comment: Did you try relationship ?

Comment: Yeah I added File: Content using File

Comment: take a screenshot of the view and attach to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view of files.

Add a relationship 'File Usage: Content'

Add a field 'title' and set the relationship on it to the one you created above.

Adjust the rest of the view as needed, ie add contextual filter Content: Image:fid